# Use a variable directlly inside an XMLNS document?

Tags: xml, windows, variables, xslt, xml-namespaces

I've made an XMLNS file with `Windows System Image Manager` tool included in the `WAIK` package, the XMLNS file is to unattended install Windows 8.1, well now I would like to add some variables in the XMLNS file to set up some values like the `UserName`, the `ComputerName` or the `ProductKey`.

I just need an example of how to set a variable and use it inside the attribute that I want.

For example, set a variable (this is pseudo code 'cause I don't know how to set the var):

```
<ComputerNameVariable>MyPc</ComputerNameVariable>
```

And then use the variable in the right attribute (pseudo code too):

```
...
<ComputerName><%= ComputerNameVariable %></ComputerName>
...
```

Then when the Windows installation is gonna process the XMLNS file to make the unattended installation it should read the variable value that I've previously set into the attribute so the computer name for the installation should be in this case `MyPc`

This is possibly to do?

PS: I've read something about `XSLT` but I don't know if that is compatible with this or how to integrate it, sorry, I'm an XML newbie.

This is the entire XMLNS file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
    <servicing>
        <package action="configure">
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft-Windows-CoreEdition" version="6.2.9200.16384" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="" />
            <selection name="Microsoft-Windows-Printing-XPSServices-Package" state="false" />
        </package>
        <package action="configure">
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft-Windows-Client-LanguagePack-Package" version="6.2.9200.16384" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="es-ES" />
        </package>
        <package action="configure">
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package" version="6.2.9200.16384" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="" />
            <selection name="Printing-XPSServices-Features" state="false" />
            <selection name="Printing-Foundation-InternetPrinting-Client" state="false" />
            <selection name="FaxServicesClientPackage" state="false" />
        </package>
    </servicing>
    <settings pass="windowsPE">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core-WinPE" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <UserLocale>es-ES</UserLocale>
            <UILanguageFallback>es-ES</UILanguageFallback>
            <UILanguage>es-ES</UILanguage>
            <SystemLocale>es-ES</SystemLocale>
            <InputLocale>es-ES</InputLocale>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <Display>
                <HorizontalResolution>1920</HorizontalResolution>
                <VerticalResolution>1080</VerticalResolution>
                <ColorDepth>32</ColorDepth>
            </Display>
            <UserData>
                <ProductKey>
                    <WillShowUI>Never</WillShowUI>
                    <Key>334NH-RXG76-64THK-C7CKG-D3VPT</Key>
                </ProductKey>
                <AcceptEula>true</AcceptEula>
                <Organization>Elektro Studios</Organization>
                <FullName>Christian Soriano</FullName>
            </UserData>
            <EnableNetwork>true</EnableNetwork>
            <EnableFirewall>true</EnableFirewall>
            <Restart>Restart</Restart>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="specialize">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <AutoLogon>
                <Enabled>true</Enabled>
                <LogonCount>1</LogonCount>
                <Username>Administrator</Username>
            </AutoLogon>
            <ComputerName>Elektro-PC</ComputerName>
            <ProductKey>334NH-RXG76-64THK-C7CKG-D3VPT</ProductKey>
            <RegisteredOrganization>Elektro Studios</RegisteredOrganization>
            <TimeZone>Romance Standard Time</TimeZone>
            <WindowsFeatures>
                <ShowInternetExplorer>false</ShowInternetExplorer>
                <ShowMediaCenter>false</ShowMediaCenter>
                <ShowWindowsMediaPlayer>false</ShowWindowsMediaPlayer>
            </WindowsFeatures>
            <Themes>
                <WindowColor>0</WindowColor>
            </Themes>
            <DisableAutoDaylightTimeSet>false</DisableAutoDaylightTimeSet>
            <BluetoothTaskbarIconEnabled>false</BluetoothTaskbarIconEnabled>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-HelpAndSupport" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <HelpAndSupport>
                <Manufacturer>Elektro Studios</Manufacturer>
            </HelpAndSupport>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <UserLocale>es-ES</UserLocale>
            <UILanguageFallback>es-ES</UILanguageFallback>
            <UILanguage>es-ES</UILanguage>
            <SystemLocale>es-ES</SystemLocale>
            <InputLocale>es-ES</InputLocale>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-SPP-UX" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <SkipAutoActivation>true</SkipAutoActivation>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="oobeSystem">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <OOBE>
                <HideEULAPage>true</HideEULAPage>
                <SkipUserOOBE>true</SkipUserOOBE>
                <SkipMachineOOBE>true</SkipMachineOOBE>
                <ProtectYourPC>3</ProtectYourPC>
                <NetworkLocation>Home</NetworkLocation>
                <HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>true</HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>
                <HideOnlineAccountScreens>true</HideOnlineAccountScreens>
                <HideOEMRegistrationScreen>true</HideOEMRegistrationScreen>
                <HideLocalAccountScreen>true</HideLocalAccountScreen>
            </OOBE>
            <VisualEffects>
                <FontSmoothing>On</FontSmoothing>
                <SystemDefaultBackgroundColor>0</SystemDefaultBackgroundColor>
            </VisualEffects>
            <TimeZone>Romance Standard Time</TimeZone>
            <DisableAutoDaylightTimeSet>false</DisableAutoDaylightTimeSet>
            <BluetoothTaskbarIconEnabled>false</BluetoothTaskbarIconEnabled>
            <Themes>
                <WindowColor>0</WindowColor>
            </Themes>
            <WindowsFeatures>
                <ShowInternetExplorer>false</ShowInternetExplorer>
                <ShowMediaCenter>false</ShowMediaCenter>
                <ShowWindowsMediaPlayer>false</ShowWindowsMediaPlayer>
            </WindowsFeatures>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <InputLocale>es-ES</InputLocale>
            <SystemLocale>es-ES</SystemLocale>
            <UILanguage>es-ES</UILanguage>
            <UILanguageFallback>es-ES</UILanguageFallback>
            <UserLocale>es-ES</UserLocale>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="auditSystem">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <Themes>
                <WindowColor>0</WindowColor>
            </Themes>
            <WindowsFeatures>
                <ShowWindowsMediaPlayer>false</ShowWindowsMediaPlayer>
                <ShowMediaCenter>false</ShowMediaCenter>
                <ShowInternetExplorer>false</ShowInternetExplorer>
            </WindowsFeatures>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="auditUser">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <Themes>
                <WindowColor>0</WindowColor>
            </Themes>
            <WindowsFeatures>
                <ShowWindowsMediaPlayer>false</ShowWindowsMediaPlayer>
                <ShowInternetExplorer>false</ShowInternetExplorer>
                <ShowMediaCenter>false</ShowMediaCenter>
            </WindowsFeatures>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <cpi:offlineImage cpi:source="wim:c:/users/administrador/desktop/es_windows_8_x64_dvd_915404/x64/sources/install.wim#Windows 8" xmlns:cpi="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:cpi" />
</unattend>
```

Comment: While it may be possible to solve your problem with XSLT, I can hardly see an advantage over the more simple text replacement. For XSLT you need a) an XSL file, which we might generate for you as an answer. It will mainly contain parts of what you have posted here b) an input XML file which contains the variables. c) an XSLT processor - and for this point, I'm not sure at which point of your unattended Setup procedure you would integrate such a tool. Can you give us some hints, e.g. whether you prepare the files on your admin machine or not.

Comment: @Thomas W thankyou for your time but don't worry I think that it's an impossible mission because the Windows setup just processes the XML file as is, I mean, just the text inside, I think XSLT can't help and is laborious. I've tried to use XML entities, I'm not an XML expert but that seems like a kind of variables that can be set/expressed directlly in a xml file without needing a XML parser/processor to read the variables, I'm not sure of what I'm saying 'cause maybe it's a crazy idea with no sense to try this on a plain text file, but anyways I've tried to set XML entities without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to modify the xml-file before it is being used. I.e. the installation processes stills sees a static file, but it is modified for that pariticular install, e.g. via a replace with a batch script. You might also want to use a temp directory so the xml-file doesn't conflict because it's being used by many users.

More details are described here - in German, but running it via Google translate or something similar should give you an idea.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/de-DE/b13b59c3-ab93-4aa5-b4cd-e7238aa88e83/umgebungsvariable-wds-deployment-mit-waik-autounattendxml?forum=windowsdeploymentde